# R Select n rows for each condition for each participant

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have this data frame about multiple single studies. A behavioral intervention was implemented for three participants (ID_AB2) and data were collected for both the baseline and the intervention condition (PhaseAB2: A = baseline; B = intervention). Finally, "Occassions" is a variable containing the number of the session.

What I was trying to do is to write a code to obtain the last three values for each phase for each participant and then compute the average.

```
 RateAB2 <- c(8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 8, 5, 4, 8, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 13, 8, 9, 15, 17, 9, 10, 7, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 7, 13, 18, 12, 18, 14, 17, 19, 15) %>% as.numeric()
 PhaseAB2 <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 8, len = 48)
 OccasionsAB2 <- rep(1:16, len = 48)
 ID_AB2 <- rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), each = 16)
 db5 <- data.frame(ID_AB2, OccasionsAB2, PhaseAB2, RateAB2)
```

I was thinking to use `dbdplyr::filter(OccasionsAB2 == ...)` but then the code would be strictly dependent on each particular dataset and it couldn't select different positions for participants with a different number of observations.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

RateAB2 <- c(8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 8, 5, 4, 
             8, 7, 4, 7, 7, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
             9, 6, 16, 13, 8, 9, 15, 17, 9, 
             10, 7, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 7, 13, 
             18, 12, 18, 14, 17, 19, 15) %>% 
                as.numeric()
PhaseAB2 <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 8, len = 48)
OccasionsAB2 <- rep(1:16, len = 48)
ID_AB2 <- rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), each = 16)
db5 <- data.frame(ID_AB2, OccasionsAB2, PhaseAB2, RateAB2)

db5 %>%
  group_by(ID_AB2, PhaseAB2) %>%       # for each ID and Phase
  top_n(3, OccasionsAB2) %>%           # keep last 3 occasions
  summarise(MEAN = mean(RateAB2)) %>%  # get the average
  ungroup()                            # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   ID_AB2 PhaseAB2  MEAN
#   <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 C1     A         6.33
# 2 C1     B         6   
# 3 C2     A         6.67
# 4 C2     B        12   
# 5 C3     A         4.33
# 6 C3     B        17
```

You can update the `summarise` past to

`summarise(MEAN = mean(RateAB2),
           OccasionSequence = paste0(OccasionsAB2, collapse = ","))`

to also get the ids of the occasions used in each case (as a string).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I just needed to change this part since I needed the average for each condition: group_by(ID_AB2, PhaseAB2)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `top_n(-3...`?

Comment: No, because it's TOP and always works in descending order. `-3` will get you the smallest numbers. Check `?top_n` where is says "If n is positive, selects the top n rows. If negative, selects the bottom n rows."

Comment: The `top_n()` above is equivalent to `arrange(desc(OccasionsAB2)) %>%
  slice(1:3)`